# Pass parameter to python.requests get string

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having issues passing a parameter to the r=requests.get statement, please see my code snippet below.

```
    cursor.execute(query, () )

for (var1, var2, var3) in cursor:
    payload = {'q' : 'var3'}
    r = requests.get(url='https://www.threatminer.org/host.php?', params=payload)
    print(r.url)
```

print(r.url) returns the following value https://www.threatminer.org/index.php, I am expecting to see https://www.threatminer.org/host.php?q=var3. I'm still new to python in general so I am sure that I am missing something simple.Thanks for the help.

Edit: So i fixed a few items but am still receiving the same results. I fixed my payload as i was attempting to pass multiple values, removed the trailing ? and added a User Agent string.

```
  # Execution of the SELECT statement
cursor.execute(query, () )

for (var1, var2, var3) in cursor:
    url = 'https://www.threatminer.org/host.php'
    payload = {'q': 'var3'}
    headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
    print(r.url)
```

Comment: What you have looks correct.  The trailing `?` on the url is unnecessary, but it shouldn't break anything either.

Comment: The website is probably seeing that you are not a proper browser and denying you access. You could try and see what happens when you change your browser's User Agent String and try to access it.

Comment: Sometimes its just so simple. Changed, payload = {'q': 'var3'} to payload = {'q': var3}